# How to define parameter for parent component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, url, routes

I have a class component, that has two subcomponents called students and stats. I have these routes configured for them for now:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: ClassComponent, children: [
      { path: 'students', component: StudentsComponent },
      { path: 'stats', component: StatsComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

And class itself is the child of another component called school.

Now routes are working fine in this level. That is, when browser URL is changed to `domain.com/class/students` I get students component, and when it's changed to `domain.com/class/stats` I get stats component.

However, now I need to pass `classId` as a parameter to the aforementioned routing. I'm stuck at this point, as I have no idea how to include that parameter in routes. Any help is appreciated.

**Update**: I know that I can have `/class/students/1` and `/class/stats/1` routes. What I want is to have them like this: `/class/1/students` and `/class/1/stats` and also define them only in the class component, not in the children component, and access them both in parent and children components.

Answer (score 2):

You can do for example:

{ path: "students/:id", component : StudentsComponent }

Then you will have an Id in the url. In the students component (or maybe a different component - for example StudentsDetailsComponent you will need to get that from the ActiveRouter service.

The constructor of the component:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute

) {}
```

Then in the code:

```
  let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Check this link https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: This is not the answer. I want to define parameter at the level of the parent component, not each children. I also need to access the parameter from the parent component.